# How can I add JavaScript inside Blogger?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I would like to add some JavaScript inside Blogger.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open("http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
    "status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0");
</script>
```

If I edit the HTML and I add `"` and `'` they get converted to `quote  ...`

If I add an HTML/JavaScript widget the code won't run.

Comment: Add the script part to head tag of blogspot template Design > Template > Customize and Save the template. The blog post should now show the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Navigate to the Layout tab, click the "Add a Page Element" option and select the "HTML/Javascript" sub-option.

See the [Layout Guide](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/43708?hl=en) for more details.

Answer (score 17):

Create a post. Click to enter html as opposed to compose. Type your script. To the right Click *Post Settings* >> *Options* >> *Compose Mode* then change *Show HTML Literally* to *Interpret HTML*. It should now accept your script as a script intsead of text..

Comment: Warning: I have found that this works fine, but you must never return to the Compose view or your JavaScript will disappear, always stay in HTML view for that post.

Answer (score 16):

Add your code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

window.open("http://www.page.html", "myWindow", 
    "status = 1, height = 400, width = 400, resizable = 0");

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run this code as an external source on your blog. How? Follow the below steps:

Step 1: Store your JavaScript code in github.com, pastebin.com or any file CDN.

Step 2: Use the below piece of code to call your JavaScript code from that external source:

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js"/></script>
```

Include this code inside `<head>`.

Answer (score 4):

Select Template. And click 'Edit HTML'. Now you can add your script.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add it to the page template.  You can edit them from within the Blogger interface or download/edit/upload them.

Comment: Add the script part to head tag of blogspot template Design > Template > Customize and Save the template. The blog post should now show the correct behaviour.