# How to add Javascript into Blogger pages?

Tags: javascript, blogger

> I have made a blog using blogger and now I want to customize it. All I want is to be able to add a button having Javascipt's onclick() in blogger's page behind HTML. I tried all the tricks but it is somehow not working.

```
<div>
<div>
<img src="C:\Users\dell\Desktop\goldfavicon.jpg" height="98px" width="98px"/>
</div>
<div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
window.open("http://www.amazon.com/tinny-tots-baby-bottle-cover/p/itme3h9rvenhxvxb?pid=BTCE3H9RGFD3Z7JR","_self")
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i add javascript inside blogger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449733/how-can-i-add-javascript-inside-blogger)

Comment: Read the question properly before you answer it.

Comment: Plz remove the topmost comment about duplicacy of the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem recently.

You need to wrap your script like so

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
window.open("http://www.amazon.com/tinny-tots-baby-bottle-cover/p/itme3h9rvenhxvxb?pid=BTCE3H9RGFD3Z7JR","_self")
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The term CDATA tells the XML parser not to parse the wrapped text data. For more info on CDATA, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html).

Also I followed [this advise](http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2013/08/how-to-correctly-add-javascript-codes-in-blogger.html):

> Adding Scripts in Blogger is extremely straightforward. All you need
>   to do is to go to Blogger.com >> Your site >> Template >> Edit HTML.
>   Now it depends on you where you would like to paste your JavaScript
>   coding. However, we prefer you to add it above the  tag because
>   this is the place where all technical things are present.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are an angel! Love you boss!